# Use an array as bindable variable in Binding.scala

Tags: binding.scala

The number of parameters in my case class for the data field changes dynamically.

So, can a `Var` also bind a `js.Array` in Binding.scala?

I tried following code without success:

```
case class Data(d: Var[js.Array[String]])
val data = Vars.empty[Data]

{
  for (x <- data) yield {
    val y: js.Array[String] = x.d.bind
    y.zipWithIndex.foreach{case (v, i) => <th>{ y(i) }</th>}
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Vars[String]`?

Comment: In fact, the internal cache in a `Vars[String]` is a `js.Array` for the JS backend.

Answer (score 2):

I could bring it to work on [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/bEkhBd3/3).

In essence you have to put each array or option in a Constants object, like:

```
  @dom
  def render = {
      val bindData= data.bind
      <div>
        {Constants(bindData: _*)
           .map(a => dataElem(a))
           .map(_.bind)}
      </div>
    }
```

It should have:

1. Bind the data: `val bindData= data.bind`
2. Put Element around: `<div>` Put
3. Array in Constants constructor: `Constants(bindData: _*)`
4. Call Element with each data-element: `.map(a => dataElem(a))`
5. Bind each result: `.map(_.bind)`

So you go down level by level.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from [Binding.scala: Strategy to avoid too many dom-tree updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364461/binding-scala-strategy-to-avoid-too-many-dom-tree-updates) and have to mention that binding directly on Vars is slow compared to for comprehension.

You should always use for comprehension on `Vars`, except you are doing some aggregation that must work on the whole list.

For your example, I've created an updated ScalaFiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7lCiigL/0