# Binding.scala: Strategy to avoid too many dom-tree updates

Tags: scala, scala.js, binding.scala

In my project [scala-adapters](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters) I display log entries that are sent over a websocket.

As I have no control on how many entries are sent, I am looking for a strategy to avoid that the screen freezes.

I created a ScalaFiddle to simulate that: [https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kzr28tq](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kzr28tq/2)

This function with these parameters works perfectly:

```
setInterval(1000) { // note the absence of () =>
  entries.value += (0 to 100).map(_.toString).mkString("")
}
```

If the interval gets smaller and the String longer - the screen freezes, e.g. with:

```
setInterval(100) { // note the absence of () =>
  entries.value += (0 to 10000).map(_.toString).mkString("")
}
```

Is there a solution to solve that on the client side - or do I have to solve that on the server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
@dom
def render = {
  <div>
  {
    for (entry <- entries) yield {
      entryDiv(entry).bind
    }
  }
  </div>
}
```

The problem is that you bind entries too early. Binding.scala does its magic by CPS transform, every `.bind` triggers re-evaluation of all code after, so you should bind a variable as late as possible.

And for `Vars`, use for comprehension instead of bind directly, to avoid updating the whole list. When you use `+=` to modify the content of `Vars`, Binding.scala "patches" the list internally, but if you do `.bind` on the `Vars` instance directly to get the whole list, the framework cannot do any optimization for you.

Here is the updated ScalaFiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kzr28tq/3