# Binding.scala: Strategy to have a defined length of a Vars

Tags: scala, scala.js, binding.scala

This is related to [binding-scala-strategy-to-avoid-too-many-dom-tree-updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364461/binding-scala-strategy-to-avoid-too-many-dom-tree-updates)

In my project [scala-adapters](https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters) I display log entries that are sent over a websocket.

I have no control on how many entries are sent. So if there are a lot of entries the screen freezes.

I created a ScalaFiddle to simulate that: [https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kzr28tq](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kzr28tq/4)

What is the way to restrict the length of the entries (`Vars`) or what is the best strategy to drop the first entry of a `Vars` if the maximum length is reached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple options:

- If you don't need to keep all the data around, simply replace it in the ListBuffer: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fsaJbkc/2

  ```
  if (entries.value.length > display)
    entries.value.remove(0, entries.value.length - display)
  entries.value += (0 to 1000).map(_=>Random.nextInt(9)).mkString("")
  ```
- If you do need to keep all the data around but want to display a subset, use another Binding based off the first: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/i75YiYN/2

  ```
  val displayedEntries = Binding {
    val allEntries = entries.bind
    if (allEntries.length > display)
      allEntries.drop(allEntries.length - display).toList
    else
      allEntries.toList
  }
  ```

No change here:
`entries.value += (0 to 1000).map(_=>Random.nextInt(9)).mkString("")`

Comment: `entries.bind` is deprecated. It can be replaced to `entries.all.bind`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `entries.all.bind` is not perfect because it suppress the ability of partial rendering.

Comment: Ideally, there should be method to create bindable slices: `def slice[A](bindingSeq: BindingSeq[A], from: Binding[Int], until: Binding[Int]): BindingSeq[A]`

Comment: Feel free to create a PR for the feature of bindable slices. It should be similar to [`BindingSeq.length`](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/blob/2513682d44de2deb0087e0ee536c4e47801263cc/Binding/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/binding/Binding.scala#L999)